# PowerShell - Rename-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'NewName'

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to bulk rename a bunch of files with PowerShell, however, I run into an error which I don't know what to do with and searching for it didn't give me any solutions either.

**Error message:**

`Rename-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'NewName'.`

---

For example: `2068227794 (0x8f860be3).bnk` to `0x8f860be3_0001.bnk`

In this particular case `$hex_name` is `0x8f860be3`.

```
$source = "K:\_test"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Recurse -Include "* (0x*).*" | ForEach-Object {

   $prefix, $hex_name = ($_.BaseName).Split('()')
   Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName ($hex_name + "_0001" + $_.Extension)

}
```

Comment: That split would return three elements so $hex_Name would be an array with two elements.

Comment: What is an example file name and what would you expect the new name to be?  Data examples and expectations are important for asking good questions.

Comment: try referencing `$hex_name[0]` to get the `0x8f860be3` without the parens, or change your split to something like `$firstParen, $hex_name, $secondParenAndExt = ($_.BaseName).Split('()')`

Comment: $hex_name = ($_.BaseName).Split('()')[1]

Comment: I suppose you've already tried something like `($hex_name + "_0001" + $_.Extension).ToString()` and confirmed that does not work. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.tostring?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0. Even if you need to set as a variable within the loop and then use with the `Rename-Item`.... just a quick idea with no testing.

Comment: Oh, and for the -Path you can just use $_.FullName

Comment: @EBGreen #1: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that.  #2: I provided an example. :P  #3: Even better, thanks! :)  #4 `$hex_name` doesn't contain the entire name of the file, so using `$_.FullName` would give an unwanted result.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yes I did, I ended up with `System.Object` as file name. ._. And I know that it worked with setting up variables in the loop, but why use variables when it works without them? :D

Comment: $_.FullName would be the full name and path to the unrenamed file.

Comment: @EBGreen Actually you are right. This is from a bigger script and I deleted the wrong line, I'll change it to prevent confusion. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this question was answered in the comments, I'll answer my own question so it is marked as solved.

The error occurs as `$hex_name` is an array which contains the hex string and the rest. There are 2 simple solutions:

Selecting the item directly:

```
$hex_name = ($_.BaseName).Split('()')[1]
```

---

Assigning the unwanted rest to a new variable:

```
$prefix, $hex_name, $rest = ($_.BaseName).Split('()')
```

---

All credit goes to [EBGreen](https://superuser.com/questions/1306871/powershell-rename-item-cannot-convert-system-object-to-the-type-system#comment1941737_1306871).